# How does plaintext NSDate work?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I put it into a plist and got this in plain text view:

2010-11-03T16:37:09Z

So my "guess" is:

2010-11-03 => 3rd Nov 2010

T => time(?)

16:37:09 => 4.37:09PM

Z => ? no idea

I want to recreate this in a php file that outputs a time and date? Just want to make sure if I just copy the same as above but leave the T and Z it will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is ISO 8601 formatting (UTC, Combined):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

You can use NSDateFormatter (iOS) or date_format/date (PHP) to reformat the date before using it.

Comment: Constructed in PHP and used NSDateFormatter to display on device. Thanks for your help.